# Closure: Which academic subjects examine human reading?

Tags: discussion

Can [Which academic subjects examine human reading?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/87469/13306). please be reopened? I've tried to edit it for clarity. Please LMK how else I can improve?

Comment: In general, we can't just reopen a question on request because a user would like it reopened. If there is a specific reason to do so, that should be explicitly mentioned in the question. (This is different from the other question you asked about, since that question is originally yours and was auto-deleted.)

Answer (score 2):

- The question title and body still do not match. The question in the body seems very broad, opinion-based and possibly not within our scope.
- The existing answer matches the titular question. It would be good if you could edit your question to match that answer. You can ask the question in the body separately, but I do not consider this a good question (see above).
- You can cast reopen votes on your own questions pushing them to the reopen queue. There is no need to make a Meta post for this. This is what happened after your last edit. [Three reviewers voted to leave the question closed in its current state.](https://academia.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/62193)
- What you can use Meta for is to debate the closure, but then you would have to bring arguments. Arguments (delivered in comments) may also help you to get your question reopened through the regular mechanism.